# Check if Array.toJSON has been overridden in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to check whether the JavaScript/Browser's own Array.toJSON was overridden by any framework or script? My script is injected inside the websites and I have an issue where in some cases Prototype framework is overriding native Array.toJSON function which is buggy and causes issues.

Edit: There is no toJSON function by default. I was confused a bit as it seems Prototype framework prototypes it to an Array, and JSON.stringify is using it to convert array to JSON which was causing an issue...

Comment: well, is perhaps contains `[native code]` or like this... Also, the added prop should be enumerable with `for..in`.

Comment: If browser implemented then `Array.toJSON == "function toJSON() { [native code] }"` should be `true`. Note: `===` will be false :)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl if `Array.toJSON.toString()` this `Array.toJSON.toString() === "function toJSON() { [native code] }"` will work

Comment: There isn't a method called `Array.toJSON` is there? It's certainly not in [this list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: @georg Not if it was added as not enumerable https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: @georg it might be not enumerable if set with defineProperty https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Enumerable_attribute

Comment: @Andy you are right. There is no toJSON function by default. I edited my question and it seems JSON.stringify was using the prototyped toJSON function which was causing an issue...

Comment: Maybe this can help [**On overriding toJSON**](http://anton.kovalyov.net/p/tojson/) - It seems to show a work-around to preserve the wanted toJSON imeplementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this doesn't answer your exact question, it seems, a way to deal with Prototype's broken implementation of `Array.toJSON`  is to check if it's broken, rather than checking if it was overwridden:

```
var arr = [1,2,3], corrupted;

if (typeof arr.toJSON === "function") {
  arr = arr.toJSON();
  corrupted = !(arr && arr.length == 3 && arr[2] == 3);
}
```

More details here http://anton.kovalyov.net/p/tojson/

Hope this helps.